# Jquery file not loading on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

When i open the html file on google chrome. It is just a blank page. Nothing is loading. If i take out the .js files it loads the content with the .css applied but never with the .js files. Whether I put the .js files in the  or at the end of the  it still does not show anything. I am using jquery btw and downloaded the file. all files are on the same folder. also tried both jquery-3.3.1.min.js and jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js if it makes a difference. Hoping someone can help. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testing.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="products">
  <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Blocks</h1>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ul>
      <li data-id="1" class="credit"> 10000$ </li>
      <li data-id="2" class="debit"> -10000$ </li>
      <li data-id="3" class="credit"> 10000$ </li>
      <li data-id="4" class="credit"> -10000$ </li>
      <li data-id="5" class="credit"> Bank </li>
      <li data-id="6" class="debit"> Loan </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="shoppingCart1" class="shoppingCart">
  <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Credit Side</h1>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol>
      <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="shoppingCart2" class="shoppingCart">
  <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Debit side</h1>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol>
      <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

.JS

```
$("#products li").draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"
});
$("#shoppingCart1 ol").droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ".credit",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.find(".placeholder").remove();
    var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
    if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
    $("<li></li>", {
      "text": ui.draggable.text(),
      "data-id": productid
    }).appendTo(this);
    // To remove item from other shopping cart do this
    var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
    $(".shoppingCart:not(#" + cartid + ") [data-id=" + productid + "]").remove();
  }
}).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
  sort: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
  }
});
// Second cart
$("#shoppingCart2 ol").droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ".debit",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.find(".placeholder").remove();
    var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
    if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
    $("<li></li>", {
      "text": ui.draggable.text(),
      "data-id": productid
    }).appendTo(this);
    // To remove item from other shopping chart do this
    var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
    $(".shoppingCart:not(#" + cartid + ") [data-id=" + productid + "]").remove();
  }
}).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
  sort: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
  }
});
```

.CSS

```
h1 { padding: .2em; margin: 0; }
#products { float:left; width:200px; height: 600px; margin-right: 20px; }
#products ul {list-style: disc; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em;}
.shoppingCart{ width: 200px; margin: 20px; float: left; }
.shoppingCart ol { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em; list-style-type: decimal;  }
```

Comment: Can you show the version that does not work?  The current one is including the migrate but not the jquery include

Comment: Also the draggable and droppable methods are not core jquery.  Those are jquery ui plugins and you will have to include the jquery ui file to use those.  Ref. https://jqueryui.com/  So your include jquery, then migrate, then jquery ui, and finally your custom logic.

Comment: Add jquery script in your head tag instead of the body tag. When the browser loads HTML page. It loads jquery library and it's ready to use the script you wrote.

Comment: will try it now.

Comment: ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">```

Comment: @supritshah1289 that's the core library.  Using the same CDN, the jquery ui include can also be gotten, such as `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">`.  Both are needed due to the OPs script using jquery ui methods.

Comment: i tried using the jsfiddle and somehow it works there if i use a different version of jquery. but when i tried the 1.9.1 cdn it is still not doing the same thing as to when in jsfiddle

here is the sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/cq0z8tzh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Because `jquery-migrate` not contains entire jquery code.
Of course you can include script from local.

Comment: i tried using the jsfiddle and somehow it works there if i use a different version of jquery. but when i tried the 1.9.1 cdn it is still not doing the same thing as to when in jsfiddle

here is the sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/cq0z8tzh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. Your HTML files do not have CDN links to jquery and jquery UI. They require in the same order. First, you need jquery CDN and second jquery UI cdn
2. You're using jquery in a testing.js file but you do not have document.ready function.

Solution:
1. Add cdn links for jquery and jquery UI
2. Wrap your javascript code within document.ready function. 
Here is a [MDN document](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[Solution](https://github.com/supritshah1289/StackOverflow-example)